# Azure Web App webconfig "Virtual applications and directories"

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

In Azure is it possible to set "Virtual applications and directories"(see screenshot below) through web.config?

[image]

Because in our Azure Portal I have no permission to change anything but can only upload .Net Core solution through Visual Studion. So not sure if I can add another "website" through applying changes to web.config

I have the following web cofig, not sure if adding "aspNetCore" can allow me to create a new website.

[image]

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**It is impossible.**

The settings in web.config are effective for web programs.

The `Virtual applications and directories` setting in Portal is an extension of the functions supported by IIS. For virtual applications and directories, they should be at the same level as wwwroot.

If you still have questions, it is recommended to [raise a support ticket for help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Is there I can edit it without going through the GUI?

Comment: According to the previous ticket I submitted to ask whether the official supports `Virtual applications and directories`, there should be no plans at the moment, so no, you can continue to try to consult the official.